# Jenkins Fails to Start

Tags: java, jenkins, freebsd

We have a server running FreeBSD 9.1-p17 and Jenkins. I interact with it via PuTTY. We upgraded from Jenkins 1.458 to 1.570, via FreeBSD's ports collection. Due to this problem with starting, we decided to reinstall.

First we uninstalled Jenkins, then we moved the main Jenkins folder (/usr/local/eweru-dev/jenkins) to a backup location, and reinstalled (again, from the ports collection). When we reinstalled, we kept the user 'jenkins' from the last install.

Now, when we try to start Jenkins, we get an error. The error below is from when we try to start it by navigating to /usr/local/share/jenkins and typing `java -jar jenkins.war`. When we try to run it as a service (with `service jenkins onestart`), we get a very similar message.

The exception looks similar to the one from [this blog](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jenkins_hudson_util_awtproblem_java), but I have tried connecting Jenkins to openjdk 7 and 8 to no avail.

Is information from our old Jenkins install finding its way into this one, breaking stuff? Or maybe there's some compatibility issue with FreeBSD 9.1.

```
Running from: /usr/local/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Jul 18, 2014 10:53:51 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Jul 18, 2014 10:53:51 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
Jul 18, 2014 10:53:55 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Jenkins home directory: /homes/maxerdwien/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
Jul 18, 2014 10:53:55 AM hudson.util.BootFailure publish
SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
hudson.util.AWTProblem: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:182)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at Main._main(Main.java:293)
        at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.awt.X11FontManager.getDefaultPlatformFont(X11FontManager.java:779)
        at sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:433)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:376)
        at sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:32)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
        at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:83)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
        at java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:490)
        at java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1219)
        at java.awt.Font.getFamily_NoClientCode(Font.java:1193)
        at java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1185)
        at java.awt.Font.toString(Font.java:1682)
        at hudson.util.ChartUtil.<clinit>(ChartUtil.java:229)
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:181)
        ... 19 more

Jul 18, 2014 10:53:56 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: Failed startup of context w.{,file:/home/maxerdwien/.jenkins/war/},/homes/maxerdwien/.jenkins/war
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at jenkins.util.groovy.GroovyHookScript.run(GroovyHookScript.java:63)
        at hudson.util.BootFailure.publish(BootFailure.java:43)
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at Main._main(Main.java:293)
        at Main.main(Main.java:98)

Jul 18, 2014 10:53:56 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
Jul 18, 2014 10:53:56 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled
```

Any help would be very appreciated. I've been googling for days.

Comment: It is a guess but check your X service in your linux. If it is not running try to start it. http://www.perpetualpc.net/srtd_xinit.html

Comment: What do you mean by "tried connecting Jenkins to openjdk7 and 8"?  Do you mean that you have both installed on your system?  I believe the recommended JDK for that Jenkins version is openjdk7.  Unless you have a need for multiple JDKs on your system, you might consider uninstalling all of them and then reinstalling just the one you want (openjdk7).  That probably won't fix anything, but at least it will limit the possible sources of error.

Comment: @cgon How do I check if it is running? "ps -A" doesn't show anything that looks like X service.

Comment: @dg99 You're right, the default JDK is openjdk7. On the advice of [this blog post](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jenkins_hudson_util_awtproblem_java), I added a line to rc.conf that read `jenkins_java_home="/usr/local/openjdk8` to override the default. Jenkins has no way of knowing that other JDKs even exist on the machine, so as you say, it probably won't fix anything. Besides, there are other programs on the server that require different JDKs.

Comment: It is (unfortunately) not uncommon for different versions of the same software to conflict by overwriting each other's files in certain shared locations.  When that happens, even if you tell Jenkins to use jdk8, it may have no choice but to load some jdk7 files.  Again, I'm not sure that's the problem, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: When you say you "reinstalled", are you referring to jenkins or the operating system? If you're getting 1.570, your ports tree may be out of date, try updating it. I wouldn't recommend having multiple JDKs installed, that will just make things confusing. Jenkins works well with openjdk7. Jenkins expects to be headless, so adding that manually shouldn't be needed. And you should always use the rc script for jenkins, not start it manually. It sets JENKINS_HOME, which you are not setting, I think that is the source of the issue.

Comment: @Steve Wills We reinstalled Jenkins, not the OS. Our ports tree was up to date when we did the update.

When we attempted to start Jenkins from the rc script, we got almost exactly the same message as above. The only difference was that webroot and the Jenkins home directory were in different locations.

As for the headlessness, I don't know what to say. The solution I posted worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FreeBSD server is a headless server. So it doesn't have any graphics installed, including fonts.

For some reason, Jenkins tries to access fonts when it loads. This behavior can be suppressed by adding the option `-Djava.awt.headless=true` to the container JVM. This is the solution that worked for me.

It looks like some operating systems recognize this type of error, but FreeBSD does not. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+got+java.awt.headless+problem

Comment: Font names are being fetched by using x service. "The FreeBSD server is a headless server." this is a wrong argument. You can configure to use it if you have any video card available to your os:http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/x-config.html

Answer (score 2):

Check the permission of the jenkins folder. make sure the user run the jenkins server have the permission to access the folder.

Answer (score 1):

For me `-Djava.awt.headless=true` didn't help at all. In fact, it's already specified in the Fedora default config, so chances are it's also in the default FreeBSD config. For me it missed the fontconfig package.

Details: http://vault-tec.info/post/98877792626/jenkins-service-unavailable

Answer (score 1):

Am facing the same issue here, and adding -Djava.awt.headless=true doesn't help. I downloaded jenkins.war and tried running it using `java -jar jenkins.war` on windows 7 & 10 and it doesn't work. Am running java version,

```
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

**The solution that worked for me**,
1. Uninstall all versions of java and updates from your system
2. Cleanup temporary files and registry (I used CCLeaner)
3. Download latest version from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
4. Install and like this comment if this solution worked for you !

*Additionally, try removing the .jenkins directory, if possible*